# Testing default error handler in an express application results in a timeout

Tags: node.js, express, jestjs, supertest, ts-jest

When testing the default error handler of an express application, it results in a timeout. The function looks as follows:

```
const createApp = (underlyingFunction) => {
  const app = express()
  app.get('/my-endpoint', async (req, res) => {
    await underlyingFunction()
    res.send({ success: true })
  })

  const errorHandler: ErrorRequestHandler = (error, req, res, next) => {
    console.error('Unhandled exception');
    console.error(error);
    console.error(error.stack);
    res.status(500).send({
      message: 'Oh dear',
    });
    // next()
  }

  app.use(errorHandler)
  return app;
}
```

And the test looks as follows:

```
  test('error should be handled and return 500', async () => {
    underlyingFunction.mockImplementation(() => {
      throw new Error('Something went wrong')
    })

    const app = createApp(underlyingFunction)
    const response = await request(app).get('/my-endpoint')

    expect(response.status).toBe(500)
  })
```

When running the test, I get the following error:

```
    thrown: "Exceeded timeout of 5000 ms for a test.
    Use jest.setTimeout(newTimeout) to increase the timeout value, if this is a long-running test."
```

What could be causing this?

Comment: What do `underlyingFunction` and `createApp` look like? Create a minimal, reproducible example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For **`express` V4**, from the [Error Handling#Catching Errors](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html) doc, we know:

> For errors returned from asynchronous functions invoked by route handlers and middleware, you must pass them to the `next()` function, where Express will catch and process them.

Although the `underlyingFunction` of the mock in the test case is synchronous, but in the route, the `async/await` syntax converts this route handler into asynchronous code.

So, you need to use `try...catch` statement to catch the error raised from `underlyingFunction` function. And pass the `error` to the `next` function. `express` will route the request to the error handler middleware with that `error`.

E.g.

`app.ts`:

```
import express from 'express';
import { ErrorRequestHandler } from 'express-serve-static-core';

export const createApp = (underlyingFunction) => {
  const app = express();

  app.get('/my-endpoint', async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
      await underlyingFunction();
      res.send({ success: true });
    } catch (error) {
      next(error);
    }
  });

  const errorHandler: ErrorRequestHandler = (error, req, res, next) => {
    console.error('Unhandled exception');
    res.status(500).send({ message: 'Oh dear' });
  };

  app.use(errorHandler);
  return app;
};
```

`app.test.ts`:

```
import request from 'supertest';
import { createApp } from './app';

describe('68923821', () => {
  test('error should be handled and return 500', async () => {
    const underlyingFunction = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
      throw new Error('Something went wrong');
    });
    const app = createApp(underlyingFunction);
    const res = await request(app).get('/my-endpoint');
    expect(res.status).toEqual(500);
  });
});
```

test result:

```
 PASS  examples/68923821/app.test.ts (9.128 s)
  68923821
    ✓ error should be handled and return 500 (49 ms)

  console.error
    Unhandled exception

      15 | 
      16 |   const errorHandler: ErrorRequestHandler = (error, req, res, next) => {
    > 17 |     console.error('Unhandled exception');
         |             ^
      18 |     res.status(500).send({ message: 'Oh dear' });
      19 |   };
      20 | 

      at errorHandler (examples/68923821/app.ts:17:13)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        9.661 s
```